# Active Directory - RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled

Tags: active-directory, powerbi

I am pulling information from our Active Directory... however i am wanting to see which groups are internal or external.

So far on googling it seems that the

RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled

is the switch to say if it external or extgernal.

What table and field in Active Directory is that information held.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [msExchRequireAuthToSendTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2007/aa563607(v%3Dexchg.80)) attribute.

That attribute defines whether Exchange will reject emails from unauthenticated users.

"Unauthenticated" usually means "coming from outside your network", but not always. If an email is sent from inside your network via SMTP without authentication, it would still be rejected if that attribute is set to `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, but do you know what schema it is ie    group.member.msExchRequireAuthToSendTo   ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. It is just a regular attribute on the AD group object.

Comment: What are you using to pull the information from AD?

Comment: Found it.. it is group.mailreceptient.msexchrequireauthtosendto     Thanks for the help :)